# How to close an Android Material Alert Dialog Programatically?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, material-dialog

I have a dialog that appears whenever some background process is going on and displays a loading ProgressBar. I am however unable to dismiss it as the `dismiss()`  function does not work. In my code below in the `hideLoading()` function is supposed to close the dialog but `.dismiss()` doesn't work. Kindly assist.

**MainActivity.Java**

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
MaterialAlertDialogBuilder progress;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    progress = new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(LoginActivity.this);

    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (password_text.getText().length() < 5) {
                password_layout.setError(getResources().getString(R.string.valid_short_password));
            } else {
                showLoading();
            }
        }
    });
}

private void showLoading() {
    progress.setView(R.layout.loading);
    progress.setCancelable(false);
    progress.show();
}

private void hideLoading() {
    progress.dismiss();
}
}
```

Answer (score 9):

In your code, "progress" is not a dialog instance, it's a MaterialDialogBuider instance.  You should get an instance of AlertDialog by something like this.

```
MaterialAlertDialogBuilder builer = new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(MainActivity.this);
builer.setView(R.layout.loading);
builer.setCancelable(false);
AlertDialog dialog = builder.show();
```

In order to dismiss the dialog, you can call dismiss function like this.

```
dialog.dismiss();
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `progress` object is an `MaterialAlertDialogBuilder`, not an `AlertDialog` itself. You can't call dismiss on the builder. First get an `AlertDialog` object from the builder via `progress.create()`, then show it. After that, you'll also be able to dismiss it. E.g.

```java
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
MaterialAlertDialogBuilder progress;
AlertDialog progressDialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    progress = new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(LoginActivity.this);

    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (password_text.getText().length() < 5) {
                password_layout.setError(getResources().getString(R.string.valid_short_password));
            } else {
                showLoading();
            }
        }
    });
}

private void showLoading() {
    progress.setView(R.layout.loading);
    progress.setCancelable(false);
    progressDialog = progress.create();
    progressDialog.show();
}

private void hideLoading() {
    progressDialog.dismiss();
}
}
```

Note: I'm not sure how `cancelable` property works on the alert dialog, but you might also allow it to be cancelable to be able to dismiss it. If the above code doesn't work, try adding `progress.setCancelable(true)`.

Comment: It gives the error:` error: cannot find symbol MaterialAlertDialog progressDialog; `

Comment: It should be of type AlertDialog. Apparently MaterialAlertDialogBuilder also produces just AlertDialog. Fixed the code.